# Find The Duplicates using binarySearch python

Tags: python, interview-questions

I got this interview question from Pramp. You can find it online through their website: https://www.pramp.com/challenge/15oxrQx6LjtQj9JK9XlA

> #### Find The Duplicates
>
> Given two sorted arrays `arr1` and `arr2` of passport numbers, implement a
>   function `findDuplicates` that returns an array of all passport numbers
>   that are both in `arr1` and `arr2`. Note that the output array should be
>   sorted in an ascending order.
>
> Let `N` and `M` be the lengths of `arr1` and `arr2`, respectively. Solve for
>   two cases and analyze the time & space complexities of your solutions:
>   `M ≈ N` - the array lengths are approximately the same `M ≫ N` - `arr2` is
>   much bigger than `arr1`.
>
> Example:
>
> input:  `arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7], arr2 = [3, 6, 7, 8, 20]`
>
> output: `[3, 6, 7] # since only these three`

```
def find_duplicates(arr1, arr2):
    output = []

    for val in arr1:
        if b_search(arr2, val):
            output.append(val)

    return output


def b_search(A, value):
    lower_ind = 0
    upper_ind = len(A) - 1

    while lower_ind <= upper_ind:
        middle_ind = lower_ind + (upper_ind - lower_ind) // 2

        if A[middle_ind] == value:
            return value
        elif A[middle_ind] > value:
            upper_ind = middle_ind - 1
        elif A[middle_ind] < value:
            lower_ind = middle_ind + 1
    return False


#I also tested it against the test cases, and it passed all of the test cases.

# Input: [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7], [3, 6, 7, 8, 20]

print(find_duplicates([1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7], [3, 6, 7, 8, 20]))
# Output: [3,6,7]



Test Case #1
Input: [11], [11],
Expected: [11],
Actual: [11]
Test Case #2
Input: [1,3,5,9], [2,4,6,10],
Expected: [],
Actual: []
Test Case #3
Input: [1,2,3,5,6,7], [3,6,7,8,20],
Expected: [3,6,7],
Actual: [3, 6, 7]
Test Case #4
Input: [1,2,3,5,6,7], [7,8,9,10,11,12],
Expected: [7],
Actual: [7]
Test Case #5
Input: [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80], [10,20,30,40,50,60],
Expected: [10,20,30,40,50,60],
Actual: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]
Test Case #6
Input: [10,20,30,40,50,60,70], [10,20,30,40,50,60,70],
Expected: [10,20,30,40,50,60,70],
Actual: [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Given that `len(arr1) == n` and `len(arr2) == m`, the bisection method has a \$O(n \log m)\$ time complexity. Notice that it is important which array is scanned, and which is bisected. You really want `arr1` to be shorter than `arr2` (do you see why?).
- That said, in case `M ≈ N` the bisection method has \$O(n \log n)\$ time complexity. However in this case you can achieve \$O(n)\$. The same linear algorithm applied to the general case yields \$O(n + m)\$. Picking the right one (\$O(n \log m)\$ vs \$O(n + m)\$) is the core of the question as I see it.

  I intentionally do not spell the linear algorithm out. It is quite simple.
- Returning `value` from `b_search` misses an opportunity to optimize further. Notice that both arrays are sorted, therefore you don't need to search the entire `arr2` again and again: you are only interested in values to the right of where the last search ended.

  Consider instead returning an *index*. It should not be an index of the element found, but one that partitions `arr2` into strictly smaller, and larger or equal than `val`. A `bisect` module conveniently provides a `bisect_left` method:

  ```
      from bisect import bisect_left

      def find_duplicates(arr1, arr2):
          output = []
          index = 0
          for val in arr1:
              index = bisect_left(arr2, val, index)
              if arr2[index] == val:
                  output.append(val)
  ```